# Test pasting into a field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

On my web page's registration page, I have disabled pasting (with javascript) any text into the 'E-mail confirmation' field. I want to create a test to test this functionality. Is there a way for me to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#email_confirmation').bind('paste', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

Comment: How have you disabled pasting? With JavaScript?

Comment: it's basically a jasmine test

Comment: yeah I would sugest Jasmine as well, however I have never used it. let me see if I can write up a test for you.